# Start BroadcastReceiver on Boot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm trying to `run code` when the user `plug or unplug` its mobile.
I thought I can achieve this by creating a broadcastreceiver and setting trigger in Manifest to `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`.
Then launch a Service from that BOOT_COMPLETED RECEIVER and toasting debugmessage.
I launched another broadcastreceiver from the Service for `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED`.
Everthing goes well and debug messages were broadcasted, the Service executed the startprocess for `ACTION_POWER` broadcastreceiver but the receiver doesn't trigger.
Anyone got an idea how to fix it?

Code:
Manifest:

```
<application

    ...


    <receiver
        android:name="de.mrglue.nfc.BootReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="de.mrglue.nfc.BootService" >
    </service>


</application>


<receiver android:name=".PowerConnectionReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>




<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

BootReceiver:

```
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //Can't toast here
    //Starting service
    context.startService(new Intent(context, BootService.class));
}
```

Service:

```
public class BootService extends Service{

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Starting second Receiver!",   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        registerReceiver(new PowerConnectionReceiver(), filter);
        Toast.makeText(this, "done!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        stopSelf();
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }
}
```

BatteryReceiver:

```
public class PowerConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
            status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        Toast.makeText(context, "CHARGE" + isCharging, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The phone state permission is missing from your Manifest file.
Include the following permission to read phone state :

**uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE**

Comment: And what READ_PHONE_STATE has to do with my goal?

Answer (score 0):

It only needs a clean and full reboot.

**Edit No 1**
I will try to give my answer more clarity by adding more details:

The device needs a full reboot after installation of new software to see any effects of
new Broadcastreceivers which the system have to execute without having the app running. invoking the intent `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` will not have any effects to the device I think.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10337842)

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen I do not understand why this does not count as an answer. It is a possible solution for the problem. I do not want to critique or request clarification from the author because I am the author and do not see any problems with my question at the moment. But I am willing to learn so I will try to improve my answer. Thank you for your comment anyway.

Comment: An answer that short (as what it first was), is used as comment. Mainly since you do not point out a root cause etc like what you now did in your edit.